# Alternatives to saving large data in session memory

Tags: php, iis, memcached

I have problems using mencache because of the limiting storage capacity of it.

What alternatives can I do to work with thousands of users with active sessions and great information?

Saving the session to disk is not a possibility for me.

Comment: If the data is not too sensitive, and generated by the user, why not store it in the client browser? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: The information is sensitive. I can not leave it in the browser.
:(

Comment: Then you're out of options, since most other methods would store the information on the disk of your server.